# How to iterate over column values to create transformed variables in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, transform

I have 10 columns and I have to create new 10 columns of sin of original columns. How to do this in Python? I have tried it using a for loop but it is giving me an error?

My data frame is

```
d = {'col1': [0, 15, 30, 45, 60], 'col2': [0, 60, 180, 240, 300]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have created a function `transform` but how to specify all columns using `var`? I am getting an error in the below command.

```
df = df.pipe(transform, var=[0, 60])
```

sample output:

```
   col1_sin  col2_sin  col1_cos  col2_cos
0  0.000000  0.304811  1.000000 -0.952413
1  0.650288  0.000000 -0.759688  1.000000
2 -0.988032  0.580611  0.154251  0.814181
3  0.850904 -0.801153  0.525322 -0.598460
4 -0.304811  0.945445 -0.952413  0.325781
```

Comment: What do you mean by `columns`? Do you have a `pandas` dataframe? If yes, please provide sample input dataframe with expected output and your attempt to solve it.

Comment: Please also post expected output based on sample input you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided what you function is doing.  From inference **sin()** and **cos()**

Below shows how `pipe()` can be used with parameters.  In this case the functions you want to apply to all columns in the dataframe.

```
import math

d = {'col1': [0, 15, 30, 45, 60], 'col2': [0, 60, 180, 240, 300]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def pipefoo(dfa, ops=[math.sin]):
    return dfa.assign(**{f"{c}_{f.__name__}":dfa[c].apply(f) for f in ops for c in dfa.columns})

df.pipe(pipefoo, ops=[math.sin,math.cos])
```

|  | col1 | col2 | col1_sin | col2_sin | col1_cos | col2_cos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 15 | 60 | 0.650288 | -0.304811 | -0.759688 | -0.952413 |
| 2 | 30 | 180 | -0.988032 | -0.801153 | 0.154251 | -0.59846 |
| 3 | 45 | 240 | 0.850904 | 0.945445 | 0.525322 | 0.325781 |
| 4 | 60 | 300 | -0.304811 | -0.999756 | -0.952413 | -0.0220966 |